# Error including Admob in PhoneGap app

Tags: java, android, cordova, admob

I followed the instructions to add admob to a PhoneGap Android app as it's written [here](https://github.com/lukeheuer/PhoneGap-Android-Native-AdMob), but it's giving me compile-time errors. Is there anything I should do?

I get errors as follows:

1. `adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit);`
   Error: "**The constructor AdView(CordovaApp, AdSize, String) is undefined**"
2. `AdRequest request = new AdRequest();`
   Error: **The constructor AdRequest() is not visible**
3. `adView.loadAd(request);` 
   Error: **The method loadAd(AdRequest) in the type AdView is not applicable for the arguments (AdRequest)**

Full code below. Please help. Thanks

```
   package com.example.hello;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;

    import org.apache.cordova.*;
    import com.google.ads.*;
    import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.ads.AdSize;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;


    public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity
    {
        private static final String AdMob_Ad_Unit = "ca-app-pub-7789543298167063/2036477434";
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        private AdView adView;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    doAdMob();
                }
            }, 5000);         
        }

        private void doAdMob() {
            // Create the adView
            adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit);
            // Lookup your LinearLayout - get the super.root
            LinearLayout layout = super.root;
            // Add the adView to it
            layout.addView(adView);
            // This centers the ads in landscape mode.        
            layout.setHorizontalGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
            // and finally...     
            adView.loadAd(request);                    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also you could use a [cordova/phonegap admob plugin](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova): `cordova plugin add com.admob.google`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, those classes starting with com.google.ads are from the 6.4.1 or earlier versions of Admob. The tutorial you are referring to was lastly updated two years ago.

If you are using the latest AdMob library from Google Play Services, you need to remove those old classes you are importing.

Replace these code

```
import com.google.ads.*;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
```

with

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
```

Also, try to create your AdRequest as following:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adview.loadAd(adRequest);
```

UPDATE:

Try following code

```
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(AdMob_Ad_Unit);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @SLee. However, I'm left with the 1st error now. What do you suggest I do?  

- `adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit);` Error: "The constructor AdView(CordovaApp, AdSize, String) is undefined"

Comment: I got this error on `adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);`  
- The method setAdSize(AdSize) in the type AdView is not applicable for the arguments (AdSize)

Comment: Did you remove those old classes you were importing? That error occurs when you are referring to the old one which is from com.google.ads.AdSize class instead of com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize. Make sure you import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.

Comment: Ok, fixed! Thanks a lot. Do you have reference to the latest Admob code for PhoneGap? I've gone through tons of samples and they are confusing and contradicting.

Comment: Well, I haven't tried Admob code for PhoneGap. According to your old tutorial, it seems like the only difference is PhoneGap's super.loadUrl API. Basically, implementing AdMob part looks the same. You just need to use the latest libraries.